# How to use the "Except if Assigned To Category" Rule for any category

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, rules

I have set up my inbox to automatically forward and categorize emails that come in to different departments. This all works fine for most repetitive emails. 
For example, any emails where someone has placed a "New Order" will forward to the order staff and categorize itself as one of my categories. I have this set up for about 5 different categories.

Now the other emails that land in my inbox, i want those to show up as a Windows Alert. However I cannot find out how to turn on the except category rule for any email that does not get assigned a category. So far I have had to make a separate rule for each category, but this ends up putting various copies of the same email notification in the alert window.

Rule#1

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
on this computer only
display **New Email!** in the New Item Alert window
Except if assigned to **New Order Staff** category
```

Rule#2

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
on this computer only
display **New Email!** in the New Item Alert window
Except if assigned to **Receipts** category
```

Rule#3

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
on this computer only
display **New Email!** in the New Item Alert window
Except if assigned to **Sales** category
```

Rule#4

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
on this computer only
display **New Email!** in the New Item Alert window
Except if assigned to **Support** category
```

So, is there any way to have something that says "Except if assigned to *ANY* category"?

Answer (score 0):

After looking for this for 2 days I found there *IS* an option down at the bottom that says: `Except if assigned to any category`.